# Extract value from text string using format string in python

Tags: python, string, format

I have one format string and one input string, for example:

```
format_string = "name=%s, age=%d"
input_string = "name=username, age=100"
```

Any suggestions on how can I extract the equivalent values of `%s` and `%d` in a neat way?

Comment: I am pretty sure you would use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for this.

Comment: What are your constraints? Do you have to support the full [conversion specifier](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting)? What's the expected output (e.g. should age come back as a number)? Where exactly did you get stuck with your implementation; give a [mre].

Comment: `l = [s.split('=') for s in input_string.split(' , ')]` ; `d = {key: val for key, val in l} ?

Comment: sorry for not being clear, output could be in any format ( list / set etc ) containing the required values. for example `[username, 100]` in our case. I couldn't find any potential solutions for this so didn't have any coding example.

Comment: show me input example and output example

Comment: for example function `func` takes two arguments format_string and input_string and returns a list. `func("name=%s, age=%d, age_str=%s", "name=username, age=100, age_str=100")` will return `["username", 100, "100"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you want to use regular expressions or split techniques, you can try [TTP](https://github.com/dmulyalin/ttp) to extract desired values:

```
from ttp import ttp
import pprint

data = """
name=username1, age=1001
name=username2, age=1002
name=username3, age=1003
"""

template = "name={{ name }}, age={{ age }}"

parser = ttp(data, template)
parser.parse()
res = parser.result(structure="flat_list")
pprint.pprint(res)

# prints:
# [{'age': '1001', 'name': 'username1'},
#  {'age': '1002', 'name': 'username2'},
#  {'age': '1003', 'name': 'username3'}]
```